# File name pattern matching in unix shell script

Tags: unix

```
cd /DIR1/

if [ -f  abc_*] ; then

ls -l abc_*| awk 'NR >0 && !/^d/ {print $NF}' >>list.txt

chmod 664 list.txt

else

echo "file not found"

fi
```

it giving the error as "Binary Operator expected "

If any files found in the directory starting with the pattern "abc_" it should create a file called list.txt and move the filenames to list.txt

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603037/binary-operator-expected-error-when-checking-if-a-file-with-full-pathname-exists 
or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340144/please-help-me-binary-operator-expected-in-cygwin

Answer (score 0):

-f checks for the existance of a single file, you can rather use

```
if ls abc_* 2>/dev/null; then 
  do stuff
fi
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.. Can you explain what is the meaning of ls abc_* 2>/dev/null

Comment: You should not parse output of ls command..

Comment: Hi Please give me the exact command

Answer (score 0):

You could just use single liner find command like below:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "abc_*" -printf "%f\n" >> list.txt
```

find command will find your files in current (replace . with /DIR1 to find in /DIR1) directory

- `maxdepth`  - just in directory specified and not recursively within each directories.
- `name` name like abc_*
- `printf` - print just the file name without directory prefixed.